# stop rotate animation on css

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I like to know how I can stop my rotate animation (css) smoothly on random position without a interaction of a button klick.

```
span.glyphicon-arrow-up {
position: absolute;
top: 31%;
left: 36%;
margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
-webkit-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
animation-iteration-count: 2;
animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
font-size: 14.0em;

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

i hope you guys can help me. (i dont know something about javascript)

Comment: Change infinite to what ever count you need check this article http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But the animation dont stop in a random position and not "smoothly". I think I need Javascript to do this. Or is there another parameter I dont know to do this in css?

Comment: it will be better if you can provide a working jsfiddle

Comment: Can be hard because I use the Bootstrap framework and some classes I cant copy :s

Answer (score 1):

First off create a second CSS class to apply the animation. Then use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to calculate & set the rotation of the element and remove the animation class when the event is triggered. How you trigger the event is up to you; for the sake of speed & simplicity, I've just used a `click` event but you could set a timeout with a randomly generated delay to trigger it without any user interaction. I've also included a fallback for browser's that don't support the `transform` property which just sets it to `initial`.

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click",function(){
  this.style.transform=window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue("transform")||"initial";
  this.classList.remove("spin");
});
```

```css
div{
  background:#000;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
.spin{
  animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin{
  to{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
body,html{height:100%;}body{align-items:center;display:flex;justify-content:center;}
```

```html
<div class="spin"></div>
```

Note that I'm currently on a machine that doesn't have any browsers installed that still require the `transform` property to be prefixed. In my tests, prefixed properties were being translated to unprefixed ones by `getComputedStyle` but I'm not sure if that's a feature of the function or down to the fact that the browser doesn't require the prefixed version. If you notice this doesn't work in browsers that require `transform` to be prefixed then you will need to provide further fallbacks. Below is the JavaScript function edited to include full list you might require:

```
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var style=window.getComputedStyle(this);
  this.style.transform=style.getPropertyValue("transform")||style.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform")||style.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform")style.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform")||"initial";
  this.classList.remove("spin");
});
```